# Firebase onChildAdded trying to add a removed object - causes NPE

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, I am trying to make a hiking app using google maps and firebase. I am trying to write a onChildEventListener support for user-created markers. It worked with the onChildAdded - it would record any newly created markers and save them in firebase, then show them on the map as well. I removed some of the markers from the db before saving the changes for the onChildRemoved callback and currently I am getting a null-pointer exception when running the app (I assume that when it runs the onChildAdded callback it still tries to go through the already deleted objects). Here is the code for initializing the listener:

```
public void initMarkersListener() {
    final DatabaseReference markersRef = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("markers");

    markersRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
            MarkerData newMarker = dataSnapshot.getValue(MarkerData.class);
            if (!huts.containsKey(newMarker)) {
                LatLng mark = new LatLng(newMarker.getCoordinates().getLatitude(),
                        newMarker.getCoordinates().getLongitude());
                huts.put(mark, newMarker.getBody());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mark).title(huts.get(mark)));
            }
        }

        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            huts.remove(key);
        }

        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

If I change the if-check in the onChildAdded to be (huts.containsKey(newMarker)), then it does not crash, saves it into the db but does not show it on the app.

And this is my data class:

```
public class MarkerData {
private MyLatLng coordinates;
private String body;

public MarkerData() {}

public MyLatLng getCoordinates() {
    return coordinates;
}

public void setCoordinates(MyLatLng coordinates) {
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

public MarkerData(MyLatLng coords, String body) {
    this.coordinates = coords;
    this.body = body;

}
```

Here is the current JSON content of the firebase db:

```
{
"markers" : {
   "-KkjV41j6AmrHjsxuEwc" : {
     "body" : "blah",
     "coordinates" : {
       "latitude" : 47.53951248481877,
       "longitude" : 5.2395521476864815
     }
   },
   "-KkkMqnOexWlcCl06gFh" : {
     "body" : "Cold"
   },
   "-KnWNiGnxi8FDHV84VU9" : {
     "body" : "canada",
     "coordinates" : {
       "latitude" : 54.14486310256719,
       "longitude" : -103.26476879417896
     }
   }
 },
 "routes" : {
   "-KmwYdZnXo5C85CyhEih" : {
     "encodedPath" : "_}}rB_cj_G~`hxSzvp@",
     "rating" : 0
   }
 }
}
```

And here is the stack trace NPE information (where line 415 is the line
`LatLng mark = new LatLng(newMarker.getCoordinates().getLatitude(),
                        newMarker.getCoordinates().getLongitude());`):

```html
06-27 06:01:13.013 3706-3706/com.example.alexander.hikebulgaria E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.alexander.hikebulgaria, PID: 3706
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                      at com.example.alexander.hikebulgaria.map.MapsActivity$8.onChildAdded(MapsActivity.java:415)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaip.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakp.zzcxi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaks$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5756)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please post the database, you can export the database to JSON and then post it in this question

Comment: If you get a `NullPointerException`, there is also a stack trace that points exactly to the line that throws the exception. Please find the stack trace, share it in your question, and indicate the line that throws the exception.

Comment: Please share us the `exeption` that you get.